# Remove 'b' flag in CSV output

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the outputs to a CSV file in Python 3.4 but the CSV file always contains 'b' flags.  For example, b'The text output1', b'The text output2',...  I am wondering if there is a way to get rid of the 'b' flags.  I understand that this is not an issue in Python 2.X.

Here are the codes that I used

```
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, ['field'], extrasaction='ignore')
    writer.writeheader()
    test_text = mongo.test.find({'text': text})
    for t in test_text
        writer.writerow({i:v.encode('utf') for i,v in t.items()})
```

Thanks very much

------Updates-----------

Thanks very much for Tim Pietzcker, John Zwinck, and Warren Weckesser providing helpful comments and answers.  Per Warren's suggestions, if I change my codes to

```
import csv

data = [chr(0x03d5) + 'oo', 'b' + chr(0x0101) + 'r']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

I will get error message

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03d5' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

if I change my codes to

```
import csv

data = [chr(0x03d5) + 'oo', 'b' + chr(0x0101) + 'r']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item.encode('utf')])
```

I will get outputs with 'b' flags

```
b'\xcf\x95oo'
b'b\xc4\x81r'
```

Any thoughts on how this is happening and how I might be able to fix it?  Thanks again.

------Updates 2-----------

Thanks very much for Warren's solution.  The following codes worked!

```
import csv

data = [chr(0x03d5) + 'oo', 'b' + chr(0x0101) + 'r']

with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

Comment: This code isn't syntactically valid and won't even run.

Comment: It would help if you whittle down your code to something that runs on its own and shows the problem.  The code you've posted has a few extra things that distract from the real problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I have updated my post and codes per Warren's comments but the problem still seems to exist.

Comment: My guess is this is running on Windows.  Try changing the `open` call to `open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8')`

Answer (score 5):

Don't explicitly encode the strings yourself; let the writer take care of it.  For example, this code:

```
import csv

data = [chr(0x03d5) + 'oo', 'b' + chr(0x0101) + 'r']

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow([item])
```

writes the file

```
ϕoo
bār
```

with UTF-8 encoding (at least it does on my system, where `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns `'UTF-8'`).  To make the encoding explicit, you can set the encoding in the call to `open`:

```
    with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
```

If the last line is changed to `writer.writerow([item.encode('utf')])` (which converts the strings to `bytes`), it produces

```
b'\xcf\x95oo'
b'b\xc4\x81r'
```

In your example, try changing this line:

```
        writer.writerow({i:v.encode('utf') for i,v in t.items()})
```

to this:

```
        writer.writerow(t)
```

Then if that works, you could replace this:

```
    for t in test_text
        writer.writerow({i:v.encode('utf') for i,v in t.items()})
```

with

```
    writer.writerows(test_text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have updated my post and codes per your answer but the problem still seems to exist.