# php League CSV invalid string on import

Tags: php

I am importing a csv file with php League peckage, on import it prepends a character b outside the double quotes of string and this breaks the MySQL query for that column.

I have tried rtrim and str_replace but none of that helps

```
$csv = Reader::createFromPath($data, 'r');
$header = $csv->fetchone();
$stations = $csv->setOffSet(1)->fetchAssoc($header);
```

I expect the output as following

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "station_name" => "HASAN KARACA - - N KOLAY BRANCH"
    "phone" => "123456"
  ]
]
```

But the actual out is

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:9 [
    "station_name" => b"HASAN KARACA - - N KOLAY BRANCH"
    "phone" => "123456"
  ]
]
```

Please note there is b in station_name which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228914/remove-b-flag-in-csv-output

Comment: What is a "PHP League Package" or which "PHP League Package" are you using. For the benefit of those of us not sitting beside you right now

Comment: php League csv is peckage which can be used to read and write csv files. I am using league csv version 7.1

Comment: looks like you are using an unsupported version

Comment: You can try `ltrim($string, "b")`. it will remove the leading "b" character from $string